# Cannot find ClassLibrary(Xamarin.Forms) in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Iam learning Xamarin for the moment and iam following a tutorial and how to create a Xamarin project here is the link 
[This](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/xamarin-tutorial-part-1-create-a-blank-app/)
So at certain point i can't find the ClassLibrary(Xamarin.Forms) in my visual studio only that can't find it didn't know why or where is the probleme i followed wisely the intall instruction but can't find it any help if possible please 
[ScreenShot](https://www.noelshack.com/2018-31-3-1533116073-classnotfound.png)

Comment: can you share the screen shot ?

Comment: yes sure one moment

Comment: @RonakShethia Post Edited u can check the screen

Comment: potable class is deprecated and not you need to work with .net standard class because it is compatible with a wide range of frameworks. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/net-standard) you can find additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already have *Shared project* in Xamarin.Forms solution so you not need to add PCL, until you have strong reason to do so. You can do all stuff with shared project too. The article you are following is using old Visual Studio 2015(Which is no longer recommended to use) why because lot many enhancement & fixes are there in Visual Studio 2017. 
Now when it comes to adding PCL you can add see screenshot

[image]

Comment: so i just work with that Legacy Portable and that's it ?

Comment: Yeah! and still not need this too as you have shared project in your `xamarin.forms` project.

Comment: is it always that laggy nd take some minutes to show the android screen ?

Comment: when i built the solution it took sometime to show the screen it was dark then it showed up and when i tried to try it it was kinda lagging is that normal ?

Comment: It happens when you are using emulators or real device connected via data cable. When you make executable file .APK that time it will work fast.

Comment: alright do u know some good tutorials i can follow as a start because am kinda confused and don't know what to do and thanks for your time and your help i appreciate that

Comment: Here you can get beginner to advance tutorials https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/technologies/xamarin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177211/discussion-between-aouadi-slim-and-arvindraja).

Answer (score 0):

Portable Class Libraries are deprecated/outdated. Use the built in function "Cross-platform" as you have in your screenshot. Project for each platform will be created with a main library where you can have your generic code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link to the tutorial you posted, I can deduce that it is an old tutorial (nearly a year over). If you really want to learn Xamarin, I would suggest you to learn it from [Xamarin.University](https://university.xamarin.com/) or from [Xamarin Developer](https://developer.xamarin.com/getting-started/) as over the year many changes took place such as Portable Class Libraries (PCLs) are considered deprecated in the latest versions of Visual Studio.

If you still want to follow the link of the tutorial, You can proceed with ***Cross-Platforms Apps(Xamarin.Forms)*** and select ***.Net Standard*** from *Code Sharing Stragety*. Then you are good to go.

[Something worth reading in order to get familiar with xamarin and cross-platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/).